# Bootstrap with ZK in single page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, zk

I want to include bootstrap in a single ZK page.

I use this :

```
<?link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" ?>
```

And I want to apply style to this :

```
 <div class="container" style="font-size: 15px"
            id="showAbsenceDays">


            <h:h3>
                Vous aviez saisi
                <span class="label label-primary">
                    <label id="absentDays" />
                </span>

                jour(s) d'absence :
            </h:h3>
            <h:dl class="list-group">
                <h:dt class="list-group-item">
                    Congé payé :

                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">
                        <label id="restDays" />
                        j
                    </span>
                </h:dt>
                <h:dt class="list-group-item">
                    Maladie :
                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">
                        <label id="sickDays" />
                        j
                    </span>
                </h:dt>
                <h:dt class="list-group-item">
                    RTT :
                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">
                        <label id="rttDays" />
                        j
                    </span>
                </h:dt>
                <h:dt class="list-group-item">
                    Absence Client :
                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">
                        <label id="clientAbsenceDays" />
                        j
                    </span>
                </h:dt>
            </h:dl>

        </div>
```

And I already included the html tag with :`xmlns:h="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/native"`

but Only the h3 is working, the others or not.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Where did you put the namspace definition (`xmlns:h="http:/ /www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/native"`)? When I put it on the container div, all components are created fine. What do you mean by "not working"? Are they not rendered, or is the bootstrap style not applied?

Comment: i mean the bootstrap style is not applied, and I puted the namespace definition in `<window >`

Comment: Hey, I have downloaded [bootstrap here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#bootstrap-css-and-js) and imported it like this: `<?link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css"?>`. The `list-...` classes are applied fine, but I found that the `bootstrap.css` does not contain `label-primary`. Can you check in your version?

Comment: Yes it does exists.